# where in clause in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

I am new to magento. 
How can I use where in clause in magento 1. 
I have array of ids and I want rows from those ids from database.
Please help me here.

```
$stateDealersCollection = $stateDealerModel->getCollection()->distinct(true)->addFieldToFilter('state_id', array('eq' => $data['state_id']))->addFieldToSelect('dealer_id')->getData();
    $dealerIds = [];
    foreach ($stateDealersCollection as $dealer)
    {
        if (!in_array($dealer['dealer_id'], $dealerIds))
        {
            array_push($dealerIds, $dealer['dealer_id']);
        }
    }
    print_r($dealerIds);
    die;
    $dealerModel = Mage::getModel('dealers/dealer');
```

Comment: please share your current code

Comment: I added the code above

Comment: I have three tables states, dealers and state_dealers. I want on select of state i need dealers list.
I also tried to use join here but not able to write correct syntax. 
If you can help me with this, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use dealers id array `$dealerIds` in `addFieldToFilter` with `in` command like this:

```
$dealerModel = Mage::getModel('dealers/dealer');
$dealerModel->addFieldToFilter('id', array('in' => $dealerIds));
```

Hope you find your solution.

Comment: Good to hear that. welcome :)